# Select most, second most, third most... recent user in Parse

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

**I would like to do the following in retrieiving users from parse:**

1) I only want to retrieve one for that activity page (I guess query.setLimit(1)

2) I only want to retrieve the most recent one (I figure query.orderByDescending("Name"); could do)

**On another activity page, and where it gets complicated**

3) I want the second most recent user

**on Another activity page**

4) I want to retrieve the third most recent user

on Another activity page
5) I want to retrieve the 4th most recent user

on Another activity page
6) I want to retrieve the 5th most recent user

Finally if no user are found on the list, I would like to them direct them to another activity page

Below is the activity code

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Distance");
    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setConversationsList();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);


        return view;
    }

private void setConversationsList() {
    currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

    //  query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
    query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
    // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
    query.setLimit(1);
    query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
    //query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
    //query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
    query.orderByDescending("Name");




    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

        public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                    names.add(userList.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                    names.add(userList.get(i).get("Headline").toString());
                    names.add(userList.get(i).get("Age").toString());
                    names.add(userList.get(i).get("ActivityName").toString());


                    //       names.add(userList.get(i).getParseObject("ProfilePicture").;


                }




                usersListView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistview);
                namesArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                        openConversation(names, i);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error loading user list",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error finding that user",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Thanks in advance, all of the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse has a method called .setSkip(int x) - the parameter will skip the first "x" results.  If you are looking for the "nth" most recent user, set x = (n-1):

```
query.setSkip(1) // will skip the first result, giving the 2nd most recent user
query.setSkip(2) //will skip the first 2 results, giving the 3rd most recent user
```

...etc.

Also, if you want the most recent user, Parse gives a query method .findFirstInBackground:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.whereEqualTo("playerEmail", "dstemkoski@example.com");
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (object == null) {
      Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
    } else {
      Log.d("score", "Retrieved the object.");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Would there be a way to have a say if the 3rd user most recent user is not present (list only has two people), it would redirect itself to the second activity. This is because I have 5 activity, where each returns a particular user. I do not want that if theres only 4 user than an activity would be blank

Comment: I guess if you call query.setSkip(2), then in the callback, check if the object returned is null - if it's null, then nothing was returned, which would logically mean there wasn't a 3rd user in the table, then redirect to where you want to go